# Bulk insert, with a "where not exists" clause

Tags: api, data, bulk-api

Is there something analogous to SQL's `WHERE NOT EXISTS` for bulk inserting into Salesforce?

(I'm using the Bulk API to insert records into a custom table I've created by inserting a Custom Object metadata.)

Comment: Upsert is as close as you will get in a single operation

Comment: So to not overwrite any existing data, probably the best play is to just do a read, do the filtering locally, then insert the filtered records?

Comment: if that is your concern yes. You could upsert with just the external ids and the evaluate results for those with a iscreated being true. Then only upsert those records. It would update the last modified date of existing though.

Comment: Is that upsert / iscreated trick better than just using the REST API to make a SOQL query with a set of Id's to match? (" ... WHERE Id IN (Id1, Id2, ...) ")

Comment: It all depends.